# Getting error while defining a sequence of (all) Fibonacci numbers, in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, fibonacci, smlnj, unbound

here is my code:

```
val fibs =
 let
 val rec fibs_help =
 fn(n, next) => Cons(n, (fn()=>fibs_help(next, n+next)) )
 in
 fibs_help(0, 1)
 end;

val list = fibs(10)
```

And here is the error:

> Error: unbound variable or constructor: Cons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message refers to a missing data type constructor, `Cons`. It is missing because you have no data type declaration in the mentioned code. You are probably missing a line that looks like:

```
datatype 'a seq = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq)
```

If you insert that declaration at the top of your code, you get a new error message:

```
! val list = fibs(10)
!            ^^^^
! Type clash: expression of type
!   int seq
! cannot have type
!   'a -> 'b
```

You get this error because you define `fibs` as a sequence of integers, but in the last line, you refer to `fibs` as a function that takes, presumably, a number of elements you wish to extract from that sequence. There is nothing wrong with the definition of the sequence. Here's how I would format the first part of the code:

```
val fibs =
  let fun fibs_help (n, next) = Cons (n, fn () => fibs_help (next, n+next))
  in fibs_help(0, 1)
  end
```

In order to extract a concrete amount of elements from this infinite sequence into e.g. a finite list requires a little more work. Write a function `take (i, s)` that produces a list of the first `i` elements of the sequence `s`:

```
fun take (0, ...) = ...
  | take (i, Cons (n, subseq_f)) = ...
```

The base case is when you want a list of zero elements from any sequence. Consider if/what you need to pattern match on the input sequence and what the result of this trivial case is. The recursive case is when you want a list of one or more elements from any sequence; do this by including the one element `n` in the result and solve a problem of the same structure but with a size one less using `take`, `i` and `subseq_f`.

Once this function works, you can use it to get your list of ten elements:

```
val ten_first = take (10, fibs)
```